# Could not parse date parameter: Invalid Date issue in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to set the default date parameter in Bootstrap DateTimePicker. Please see the code below

```js
date = $('#drop-off').val(); // "04-07-2018  4:22 PM"
date = moment(date);
date = date.toDate();
$(a).datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A',
    defaultDate: date
});
```

This works good in Chrome, buts throws an error both in Safari and Firefox

```
TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: Invalid Date
```

Is this an issue with the time format that I pass to the moment function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the moment method to format the date. Passing an additional argument with format will fix the issue.

```
 date =  moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
   $(a).datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'
   });
   $(a).data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for both Date and Time:

> ```
>  laet _date= Date.parse(date.format('YYYY/M/D'));
>  laet _StartTime= Date.parse(time.format('H:mm'));
> ```